# Is it possible to transfer the value read from the serial port to a csv file in real time when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

> def on_searchfile_clicked(self):

```
  if self.pushBtnClicked:
        self.pushBtnClicked = False
        return
    #filesave
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "save", './', "CSV file (*.csv)")
    if not file_path:
        return
    #open file
    with open(file_path, 'a',encoding= 'utf-8',newline='') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f) 
        writer.writerow(['Num'])
        while True:
            data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            writer.writerow([data])
```

I want to accumulate the serial port value received in real time when the button is pressed in a csv file to be saved in real time.
However, when I run the above code, the serial port value is not displayed. Do you know how to fix it?  The port value was set as global in another function.

If you press the button, the directory where the csv is saved is displayed, but if you save it to a csv file and run it, the value received through the serial port is not output to the csv file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), but consider that we normally answer to specific and detailed questions. We don't provide tutorials or solutions to questions like "I'd like to know how to do xyz", and we also need a valid code (possibly, a [mre]) to start with. You mentioned a button, but your code doesn't show any of that, nor how that function is called.

Comment: Have you tried adding `print(data)` to verify you are actually getting data to output from the serial port?
  Also, your code currently enters an infinite loop while reading from the port, and may want to try changing your loop to `while data := ser.readline().decode().strip() != ""`